# Uploading file with PHP: Running into a size limitation

Tags: php

I have a problem when uploading files with PHP with size limitation. I set the maximum size to upload: 5MB, but when I upload a file more than 5MB it is still granted to continue the process but the file is not uploaded, how could I solve the problem so there will be an error if someone uploads more than 5MB. Here's my code:

Input form:

```
    <form action="kegiatan_upload_tambah.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group"><label>ID Kegiatan</label>
        <input type="text" name="id_kgt" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><label>Nama Kegiatan</label>
        <input type="text" name="nama_kgt" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><label>Keterangan</label>
        <textarea name="ket" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5"><label>Tanggal Mulai</label>
          <input type="text" name="tg_mulai" id="tg_mulai" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5"><label>Tanggal Akhir</label>
          <input type="text" name="tg_akhir" id="tg_akhir" class="form-control" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group"><label>Pilih File</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" required>
      </div>
    </div></form>
```

PHP script:

```
    $allowed_ext  = array('doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'pdf', 'rar', 'zip');
    $file_name    = $_FILES['file']['name']; // File adalah nama_kgt dari tombol input pada form
    $file_ext     = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
    $file_size    = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp     = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $lokasi       = 'file/kegiatan/'.$nama_kgt.'-'.$file_name;

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === true)
    {
      if($file_size > 5000000)
      {
        echo "<script>alert('ERROR: Max File only 5 Mb!');history.go(-1)</script>";
      }
      else
      {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $lokasi);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO kegiatan (id_kgt,nama_kgt,ket,tg_mulai,tg_akhir,nm_pengirim,type,size,file,jamlog,buatlog) 
        VALUES('$id_kgt','$nama_kgt','$ket','$tg_mulai','$tg_akhir','{$_SESSION['nama']}','$file_ext','$file_size','$lokasi',now(),now() )";
```

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Well what value is inside **$file_size** ?

Comment: Can you show me the `<input>` tag and also print out `$file_name`, `$file_ext`, `$file_size` and `$file_tmp` cause I think the file doesn't actually uploaded.

Comment: @AkiEru i've updated the input form sir

Comment: Do you forgot to put `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag? Maybe that is the reason that you cannot upload a file.

Comment: `die('<script>alert....')` instead of `echo "<script...`

Comment: @AkiEru  i've updated the input form sir

Comment: @ojovirtual still not working sir

Comment: Use the PHP `upload_max_filesize`  ini setting.

Comment: @AzmiColeJr. Can you please `var_export` the $_FILES['file']?

Comment: if i try to upload file with 373KB, the file_size export is 381952 @AkiEru

Answer (score 1):

Try this now:

```
$file_exts = array('doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'pdf', 'rar', 'zip');
    $upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
                if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/doc")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/docx")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/xls")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/xlsx"))
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/ppt"))
                    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/pptx"))
                        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/pdf"))
                            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/rar"))
                            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/zip"))

                && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5000000)
                && in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts))
                        {
                            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                            {
                                header("Location:index.php?err=filepro1");
                                //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $tempupname = time().$_FILES["file"]["name"];
                                $imgpathtostore="files/".$tempupname;
                                $imgpathtostoreDB="files/".$tempupname;
                                //Query

                                }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "file err";
                                }
```

Comment: @AzmiColeJr. try my edited code i wish it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing your logic...

Instead of saying

```
if($file_size > 5000000)
{
   //do something...
}
else 
    die("File cannot exceed 5MB in size");
```

say....

```
if($file_size <= 5000000)
{
  //do something....
}
else
    die("File cannot exceed 5MB in size");
```

Also, ensure that your form tags have the attributes method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data". You may also want to check that there are no errors in the file before uploading it. To do this...

```
$file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
if($file_error === 0)
{
  //upload file and do more cool things here....
}
```

Hope this helps...